# flutter IOS Archive -> fatal error: module 'flutter_webview_plugin' not found

Tags: flutter, plugins, webview

```
CompileC /Users/kkk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fkufrnoydejulxbgtamtkhrugtau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.o /Users/kkk/Desktop/wooribannet/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    cd /Users/kkk/Desktop/wooribannet/ios
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -target arm64-apple-ios9.0 -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -std\=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path\=/Users/kkk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/kkk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS\=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES\=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.1.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility\=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -iquote /Users/kkk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fkufrnoydejulxbgtamtkhrugtau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/kkk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fkufrnoydejulxbgtamtkhrugtau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/kkk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fkufrnoydejulxbgtamtkhrugtau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/kkk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fkufrnoydejulxbgtamtkhrugtau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/kkk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fkufrnoydejulxbgtamtkhrugtau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/include -I/Users/kkk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fkufrnoydejulxbgtamtkhrugtau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -I/Users/kkk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fkufrnoydejulxbgtamtkhrugtau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -I/Users/kkk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fkufrnoydejulxbgtamtkhrugtau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/kkk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fkufrnoydejulxbgtamtkhrugtau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/kkk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fkufrnoydejulxbgtamtkhrugtau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/kkk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fkufrnoydejulxbgtamtkhrugtau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.dia -c /Users/kkk/Desktop/wooribannet/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m -o /Users/kkk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fkufrnoydejulxbgtamtkhrugtau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.o
```

---

/Users/kkk/Desktop/wooribannet/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9: fatal error: module 'flutter_webview_plugin' not found

@import flutter_webview_plugin;

1 error generated.

---

Above is the error message.

An error occurred during IOS Archive.

I need help.

Should I not use flutter_webview_plugin?
Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions available for any kind of library/module not found.

Solution 1 :

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

If you still get a problem:

```
pod update
pod repo update
pod install
```

Try with below solution as well :

```
delete build folder
delete pod.lock file
delete .syslinks folder
delete pods folder
```

change your directory in your terminal by

```
cd ios
pod install --repo-update OR pod repo update
pod install
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Don't forget to upvote if found useful

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

### in terminal

rm -rf Pods

rm -rf Podfile.lock

pod install

---

Open xCode as runner.xcworkspace

product -> clean